# UITableView allowing some kinds of requests to be deleted with swipe gestures

Tags: comparative-review, swift, ios, cocoa

I have a tableview which shows a list of objects called Requests. It has 3 segments. Namely **Accepted**, **Received** and **Sent**. And the objects for each segment are in 3 arrays.

[image]

I want to enable deleting rows (in turn the objects) *only* for **Accepted** and **Sent** segments.

[image]

This is my current implementation.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    var deleteAction: UIContextualAction?

    switch currentShowingStatus {
    case .accepted:
        deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, view, completionHandler in
            let request = self.acceptedRequests[indexPath.row]
            completionHandler(true)
        }
    case .sent:
        deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, view, completionHandler in
            let request = self.sentRequests[indexPath.row]
            completionHandler(true)
        }
    default:
        break
    }


    if let deleteAction = deleteAction {
        let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
        configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
        return configuration
    } else {
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [])
    }
}
```

As you can see there is quite a bit of duplicating code. And I can't extract away the `UIContextualAction` declaration part because of it's completion handler. Selecting the object to be deleted happens in there.

I also can't define `UISwipeActionsConfiguration` as a local variable and reduce its duplicating due to that class must be initialized with `UIContextualAction` instances.

**Note**: You have to pass an empty actions array to `UISwipeActionsConfiguration` in order to *not* show the swipe actions in cell. Returning `nil` doesn't do it.

So all this has produced an ugly piece of code. I'm wondering if there's a better way to refactor this.

---

**Alternative Approach**

Instead of checking for segment first and then adding multiple delete actions, I put the checking for segment part inside one completion handler like this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    var actions = [UIContextualAction]()

    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, view, completionHandler in
        switch self.currentShowingStatus {
        case .accepted:
            let request = self.acceptedRequests[indexPath.row]
            self.deleteClientRequest(request)
        case .sent:
            let request = self.sentRequests[indexPath.row]
            self.deleteClientRequest(request)
        default:
            break
        }
        completionHandler(true)
    }

    switch currentShowingStatus {
    case .accepted, .sent:
        actions.append(deleteAction)
    case .received:
        actions.removeAll()
    }

    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: actions)
    configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return configuration
}
```

The downside is I still have to check for segment *again* in order to show the swipe action for just the **Accepted** and **Sent** segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first implementation you can make `deleteAction` a  *constant* if you initialize it in all cases of the switch-statement:

```
    let deleteAction: UIContextualAction?
    switch currentShowingStatus {
    case .accepted:
        deleteAction = UIContextualAction(...)
    case .sent:
        deleteAction = UIContextualAction(...)
    case .received:
        deleteAction = nil
    }
```

That makes it clear that the variable is initialized exactly once before used. I would also replace `default:` by the explicit `case received:`. That makes it obvious to reader in which case no swipe action is configured (without looking up the enum definition) and forces you to update the code if more cases are added.

The double definition of `UISwipeActionsConfiguration` could be avoided by initializing the *array* of actions instead:

```
    let actions: [UIContextualAction]
    switch currentShowingStatus {
    case .accepted:
        actions = [UIContextualAction(...)]
    case .sent:
        actions = [UIContextualAction(...)]
    default:
        actions = []
    }

    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: actions)
    configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return configuration
```

It remains the code duplication for `UIContextualAction` though.

In your alternative approach you append or remove elements from the `actions` array. But that array is initially empty. Similarly as above, you can simplify it to

```
    let deleteAction = ...

    let actions: [UIContextualAction]
    switch currentShowingStatus {
    case .accepted, .sent:
        actions = [deleteAction]
    case .received:
        actions = []
    }
```

But – as you noticed – you have to evaluate `self.currentShowingStatus` inside the closure again. I would avoid that for an additional reason: You are relying on the fact that the status has not changed when the closure is *executed.*

The code duplication for `UIContextualAction` can be avoided if you initialize the *request*  first:

```
   let request: Request?
   switch currentShowingStatus {
   case .accepted:
       request = self.acceptedRequests[indexPath.row]
   case .sent:
       request = self.sentRequests[indexPath.row]
   case .received:
       request = nil
   }

   if let request = request {
       let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {
           _, _, completionHandler in
           self.deleteClientRequest(request)
           completionHandler(true)
       }
       let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
       configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
       return configuration
   } else {
       return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [])
   }
```

Note also that unused closure parameters can be replaced by the wildcard parameter `_`.

I would probably leave it like that, but of course you can combine the techniques:

```
    let request: Request?
    switch currentShowingStatus {
    case .accepted:
        request = self.acceptedRequests[indexPath.row]
    case .sent:
        request = self.sentRequests[indexPath.row]
    case .received:
        request = nil
    }

    let actions: [UIContextualAction]
    if let request = request {
        actions = [UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {
            _, _, completionHandler in
            self.deleteClientRequest(request)
            completionHandler(true)
            }]
    } else {
        actions = []
    }

    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: actions)
    configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return configuration
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, for the very detailed answer. This looks much cleaner and concise.